# Apple Pages weird table numbering

Tags: mac, pages

In Apple Pages for Mac, if I create a table, then enable its title, and then make a copy of this table, the second table will be titled **Table 1-1** (and not **Table 2**). Is it a bug or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not a bug. It is expected behavior and works the same way with tables in Numbers and Keynote.

If you keep creating fresh new tables, they will be named consecutively as "Table 2", "Table 3", etc. However, when you copy and paste an existing table, Pages tries to duplicate it as fully as it can. But because tables are identified by their names, those in the same document need to have different names, compelling Pages to add "-1" while naming the duplicate.

Comment: Well, thanks for explanation, I think it will be fair to choose your answer as correct. Though the current way how it works doesn't make sense to me as a user. (And actually, numbering such as 1-1, 1-2, 2-1 and so on is used in some documents, including old OS X HIGs, to make it easy to say which table belongs to which numbered section.)

Comment: @jsx97 Numbers (Apple) applies the same behaviour to adding sheets compared to duplicating them. So, it makes perfect sense to be consistent. Adding a sheet will get the name "Sheet 2" or "Sheet 3" etc Duplicating Sheet 2 will give "Sheet 2-1" etc